# Filter list having two Tables join data in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two tables..

```
Student (StudentId,Name,FatherName)
Qualification (QualificationId,StudentId,DegreeName)
```

I have got data like this..

```
var myList = (from c in entities.Students
              join q in entities.Qualifications on c.StudentId equals  q.StudentId
              select new {c.Name,c.FatherName,q.DegreeName}).ToList();
```

Now i want to filter myList more.. How can i do it, like..

```
var filteredList = myList.Select(c=> new Student 
{
Name=c.Name,
FatherName=c.FatherName
//Degree=C.Degree
}).ToList();
```

The above `Linq` Query is not working if i want to get DegreeName also, My Question is how to further Filter `myList`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filteredList = myList.Where(i => i.FatherName == "Shahid").ToList();
```

Keep in mind since you called `ToList()` on the original query you are now filtering in memory. If you want to filter in the database then remove the `ToList()` on the first query and do it like this:

```
var myList = from c in entities.Students 
             join q in entities.Qualifications on c.StudentId     equals  q.StudentId
             select new {
                 c.Name,
                 c.FatherName,
                 q.DegreeName
             };

var filteredInDatabase = myList.Where(i => i.FatherName == "Shahid").ToList();
```